# contacting advisor before admission can be helpful?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I am an Mphil student from India. My field of interest is complex analysis. I plan to go abroad for my PhD. I know the process of GRE exams and all. But I want to ask, is talking to any professor, with whom you wish to work for PhD, from your desired university, helpful in getting admission? 
Can it be helpful somehow?

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/924/contacting-professors-for-phd-vacancies

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly talk with them and discuss your ideas and options and if you find the connection is a good one you could ask for a letter of recommendation from them, but short of a letter I don't think a professor has a whole lot of flex/power when it comes to admissions.

Certainly if they vouch for you that is a positive thing, but unlike a "job" I feel the role at the University is based more on your academic experience and aptitude than who you know.