# How to contact professors for a Ph.D position in France, when I don't have a research question?

Tags: phd, france

I completed Master's in Netherlands in Aerodynamics and I am looking for Ph.D in the field of aerospace in France. In Netherlands & Germany, I can see the available Ph.D offers in University website but I don't know how to search in France? I really want to stay there!

I see some people in this forum answered to contact professor directly (for example, in [What is the process for PhD applications and contacting professors in France?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16824/what-is-the-process-for-phd-applications-and-contacting-professors-in-france)) but I don't have an Ph.D research question. So, don't know how to contact them. Can someone tell me how to contact a professor and whom to contact for funding?

Comment: You can find specific professors and what is the subject they are working on. In that case, you can propose that you like the subject and would be interested in a PhD position to work with them. Although, universities usually advertise the positions on their website and/or other academic job portals.

Comment: I think it is easiest to just google and email the prospective supervisors directly (many of them would have a "now hiring" section on their webapge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Professors (and possibly alumni) at your university in the Netherlands probably have contact information for collegues around the world. If not, they could help you find someone who does.

Otherwise, the GIFAS (the national association of aerospace industries)  has published a [catalog of École Doctorales](https://www.gifas.asso.fr/sites/default/files/video/catalogue_ecoles_doctorales_gifas.pdf) and a website which has a [section about training](http://www.aeroemploiformation.com/pages/annuaire-formations-et-metiers).